# Want to make a line, using a handle to a figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, line, handle, matlab-figure

I have a problem, where I already have a handle to a figure created, and I want to somehow now draw a line, given that handle. For example, I have:

```
f1 = figure(1);
a1 = gca;
```

For commands like `plot` and `surf`, I can pass the axes and/or figure handles to tell it to plot to that particular figure. However, how do you do this with the `line` command? There does not seem to be a way as far as I know... thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `line` function, like `patch` is a low level function. The plot command are built on top of these. However you can do this:

```
f1 = figure(1);
a1 = gca;
line([0 1],[0 1],'Parent',a1); % Parent has to be an axis handle
```

You can find more line options here: [line properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line_props.html) or type `doc Line_Props` in the Matlab command window.

Comment: in what way is your answer different than [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16695115/1714410)?

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks! Its so annoying that plot/surf/imagesc/line all have different ways of doing it! ><

Comment: @Shai: They're not different. We just wrote and submitted simultaneously. I didn't even see yours. However, your answer has a small issue -see my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `Parent' property?

```
line( x, y, 'Parent', a1 );
```

see [line properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line_props.html) for more info.

Comment: The figure handle won't work. Only an axis handle (or `hggroup` or hgtransform`)